# Can't solve this simple bug

Tags: javascript, jquery

First time posting here. Got a tip from my friend that it would be good ide to ask you guys.

So the thing is i have done a quiz page and im pretty much done except from the styling.
But i have this one bug that i can't solve and neither can my friend.

**The quiz is like this**

you get a picture, recepy and 4 answers to choose from.
after you choose one you get 1 new picture and recepy
after going through 10 pictures you are supposed to get your score

This is where the bug is. Somehow the variable that counts right answers shows ridiculously high numbers.

for example: if you answer right on all the question you'll get "257 correct anwers out of 10"

I have done a quiz page and I'm pretty much done except from the styling.
But i have this one bug that i can't solve and neither can my friend.

**The quiz is like this**

you get a picture, recepy and 4 answers to choose from.
after you choose one you get 1 new picture and recepy
after going through 10 pictures you are supposed to get your score

This is where the bug is. Somehow the variable that counts right answers shows ridiculously high numbers.

for example: if you answer right on all the question you'll get "257 correct anwers out of 10"

i have no ide what is causing this. But it might be that it is looping the if-else statement.

[here's the link to the page](http://drinkquiz.comze.com/DrinkQuiz.php), so that you can test it for your selfs if you want to.

**The main.js Code.**

```
(function () {
    var numberOfQuestions = 10;
    var atQuestion = 0;
    var correctAnswers = 0;
    var questions = "";
    var askQuestion = function (question, atQuestion) {
        //
        //console.log(question.name + "  "+ atQuestion);
        $("#content img").attr("src", question.path);
        $("#recipe").html(question.recept)
        $("#btn1").html(question.Alt1);
        $("#btn2").html(question.Alt2);
        $("#btn3").html(question.Alt3);
        $("#btn4").html(question.name);
        $("#content").show();
        $("#start").hide();
        $("#btn1, #btn2, #btn3, #btn4").on("click", function (e) {
            $("#content").hide();
            var rightAnswer = question.name;
            if (rightAnswer == $(e.target).html()) {
                correctAnswers++;
                //console.log("rätt svart är" + $(e.target).html());
            } else {
                // console.log("fel svar");
            }
            var quests = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('qz'));
            atQuestion = atQuestion + 1;
            //console.log("atquestion: " + atQuestion);
            if (atQuestion === numberOfQuestions) {
                //console.log("Game over");
                $("#heads_up").html("you had: " + correctAnswers + " correct answers out of " + numberOfQuestions);
                $("#mainQuestion").hide();
                //atQuestion = 0;
                //correctAnswers = 0;
            } else {
                askQuestion(quests[atQuestion], atQuestion);
            }
        });
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#start").hide();
        $("#content").hide();
        $("#RestartBtn").hide();
        $("#mainQuestion").hide();
        $("#start").on("click", function () {
            $("#mainQuestion").show();
            $("#RestartBtn").show();
            questions = localStorage.getItem('qz');
            var qObjs = JSON.parse(questions);
            atQuestion = 0;
            askQuestion(qObjs[atQuestion], atQuestion);
        });
    });
    $.ajaxSetup({
        url: "../get_quiz.php",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        success: function (data) {
            var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);
            //console.log(jsonObj);
            localStorage.setItem('qz', JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
            $("#start").show();
        },
        error: function (object, data) {
            alert("The quiz coulnd't load!");
        },
    })
}());
```

Comment: @user: Please visit this site for a moment: http://jsbeautifier.org It'll help you post cleanly formatted code.

Comment: This is a great time to learn your debugger tools! If you're using Chrome, open the inspector, open the Javascript in the "Sources" tab, find the line that adds to the score, and click the line number next to that line. Now, when your program executes that line, it'll pause and let you inspect what's going on and how it got there.

Comment: Not related to this problem, but remove the `$` from your first line of code. You're actually telling jQuery to execute "undefined" when the page is ready, while I believe your intent was just creating a base scope.

Comment: Thanks guys! You are awesom! im kinda new to javascript and got blind to the misstakes ^^

Hopefully i'll solve this problem now if i can find out what what i should write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're adding the onclick event to the buttons each time the question changes.  So the click event fires more and more times each time.

I tested and verified.  That is the issue.  You'll either want to unbind, rebind the event, or move the ".on()" call to outside the current call.

Comment: Thank you! You guys are awesome. now i'll just try to find out how i should implement the changes :)